# Rmarkdown: PDF file can not generate with a loop

Tags: r-markdown, tinytex

I've built a for loop to generate a series of PDF files automatically, but it says:

```
output file: test_chinese.knit.md

"C:/PROGRA~2/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test_chinese.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output 1TEST.tex --template "C:\Users\adminstor\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" --variable "compact-title:yes" 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650 64-bit)
entering extended mode
! Argument of \CJK@XX has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.30             breaklinks=true}

Error: Failed to compile 1TEST.tex. See 1TEST.log for more info.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"pdflatex" -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "1TEST.tex"' had status 1 
2: running command '"pdflatex" -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "1TEST.tex"' had status 1
```

Have to mention that: The .rmd file could run successfully without the for loop.

The for loop I built is:

```
for (i in 1:5){
  cat(i, '\n')
  rmarkdown::render("test_chinese.Rmd",
                    encoding = 'UTF-8',
                    params = list(file_number = i),
                    output_file = paste0(i, "TEST.pdf"),
                    output_format = 'pdf_document')
}
```

Since I'm generating a Chinese file, the TeX Template is CTeX Template with TinyTex.

Here is my sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                               LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rvest_0.3.2    xml2_1.2.0     knitr_1.20     rmarkdown_1.10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16    magrittr_1.5    devtools_1.13.6 R6_2.2.2        stringr_1.3.1   httr_1.3.1      highr_0.6       tools_3.4.4    
 [9] xfun_0.3        tinytex_0.8     postr_0.0.0     git2r_0.23.0    withr_2.1.2     selectr_0.4-1   htmltools_0.3.6 yaml_2.2.0     
[17] rprojroot_1.3-2 digest_0.6.15   rsconnect_0.8.8 curl_3.2        memoise_1.1.0   evaluate_0.11   stringi_1.1.7   compiler_3.4.4 
[25] rticles_0.5     backports_1.1.2
```

Looking forward for your help!

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can you please include a minimal example for a failing `Rmd` file? Thanks.